# When I load next image using SOIL, it will replace all the images I load before

Tags: opengl

This is part of my coding, a simple balloon clicking game. I have a background image and another image for balloon, the code seems to replace all my previous loaded image. Helppppp

```
    GLuint tex_2d;
    GLuint tex_bg;

    int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
        glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
        glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
        glutCreateWindow("Lab Assignment");

        init();
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutIdleFunc(display);

        glutMouseFunc(mouse);

        glutMainLoop();

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

This is where I put the coding for image loading, tex_bg is background.bmp for background, and tex_2d is for balloon image. Image loaded for tex_2d replaced the background image which is loaded earlier than it.

```
    void init()
    {
        tex_bg = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
            "background.bmp",
            SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
            SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
            SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
        );

        tex_2d = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
        (
            "balloonImage.bmp",
            SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
            SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
            SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
        );

        if (tex_2d == 0 || tex_bg == 0)
        {
            printf( "SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result() );
            exit(0);
        }

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    }



    void drawQuadOutline()
    {
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_bg);
            glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawQuadOutline();

    drawCircleOutline(balloon[balloonBurst]);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}   
    void drawCircleOutline(Circle o)
    {

        float angle;

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_2d);
            for(angle=0.0f; angle<360.0f; angle+=2.0f)
            {        
                float radian = angle * (pi/180.0f);
                float xcos = (float)cos(radian);
                float ysin = (float)sin(radian);
                float x = xcos * o.r  + o.pos.x;
                float y = ysin * o.r  + o.pos.y;
                float tx = xcos * 0.5f + 0.5f;
                float ty = ysin * 0.5f + 0.5f;

                glTexCoord2f(tx, ty);
                glVertex2f(x, y);
            }

        glEnd();

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
```

Is it problem with my coding? or misuse of SOIL function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your coding is that you call `glBindTexture(...)` in-between `glBegin (...)` and `glEnd (...)`.

That is invalid; if you checked `glGetError (...)` you would know this.

#### You need to re-write this code:

```
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_2d);

    ...

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_bg);
```

#### To this:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_2d);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    ...

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_bg);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
```